# Life is a Divine Test

Tags: will-of-god

Is Divine Test a common notion among the Christians, so that they may regard life and its difficulties such as the Corona virus, earthquakes and plagues as divine tests by God to examine humans as to either purify them or specify their obedience?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack. I would like to direct you to our [tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) and to our [guide on what makes a good question on this stack](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/690/what-makes-a-good-focused-question). Although I find your question quite interesting, you could improve it by doing a bit of research on your own and incorporate that into your question. This way you can tell us what you already know and what pieces you are missing.

Answer (score 1):

> For we must all appear before the judgment seat of Christ; that every one may receive the things done in his body, according to that he hath done, whether it be good or bad.
>
> [2 Corinthians 5:10 KJV]

The thought that life is a testing process is fundamental, I would say, to cultures and ideologies throughout the world in all generations.

And it is a fundamental thought, I would say, in every Christian mind.

To prove whether or not it is, however, would require a vast amount of research and documentation and citation.

Which is why I prefer to just quote the scripture and to add a paragraph from the Westminster Confession :

> 2. Good works, done in obedience to God’s commandments, are the fruits and evidences of a true and lively faith:c and by them believers manifest their thankfulness,d strengthen their assurance,e edify their brethren,f adorn the profession of the gospel,g stop the mouths of the adversaries,h and glorify God,i whose workmanship they are, created in Christ Jesus thereunto;k that, having their fruit unto holiness, they may have the end, eternal life.
>
> [Westminster Confession Chapter 16 - Good Works](https://www.fpchurch.org.uk/about-us/important-documents/the-westminster-confession-of-faith/#cp15)